# how to send notification to all registration user using firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=AAAAGif5ioo:APA91bHGk4FI7AKSVlWDDag4WqaCOuR897tpL5TFK5rO2pEqQQ4AP4iG9zESFcYB71gfQKOZvGf-.....................................................

{
  "to": "fx7-VFWyOhc:APA91bEbD9ABoEt3gELCjMCRlezJD9vnR9h0ywFuymjmAb96PNObbL7kbnjFFal7gZiKatYU_XH_66zCiXdWzBSlBGhMBLV6pdyxP...............",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

But how to send notification to all registered devices on Firebase Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 0):

use [registration_ids](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) field in your message and you can send in groups of 1000 at a time

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging provides two ways to target a message to multiple devices:

Topic messaging, which allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic.

Device group messaging, which allows you to send a message to multiple devices that belong to a group you define.

Check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple